# Save PHP opcache to Memcached

Tags: php, php-fpm, memcached, opcode, php-memcached

Running on small servers it would make sense offloading these as much as possible for performance. Also offloading will prevent from the server becoming a bottleneck. Therefore I use memcached for sessions, database indexes, user data etc.

Question; Would it be possible to connect my PHP (Zend) Opcache to Memcached-cluster?

Ultimately multiple server reusing the opcache from memcached? It would also make it possible to giantly increase my cache size?

Answer (score 2):

The official answer is no. Opcache only supports caching in shared memory; [no other backends even exist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php). And trying to stuff the cache into memcached would just slow it down anyway, so there seems to be little point.

Comment: In case of a shared cache its size could be greatly improved (each n seperate vs sum of n's). The more that is cached, the  faster it will get, though accesstime could be slower. Also, that it isn't officially   supported, I'm still interested in the question if it would be possible?